# Deny AD-User Group to login on a certain AD-Computer Group

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have (simplified) two AD Groups for Users:

```
bgs.ac.at\Students
bgs.ac.at\Teachers
```

I have (simplified) two AD Groups for Computers (like in two rooms)

```
bgs.ac.at\Room1
bgs.ac.at\Room2
```

I want students to only be able to login computers in Room1.

I set up a Group Policy, ("denyStudents") to bgs.ac.at\Room2 and set

Computer Configuration > Policies > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment. > Deny log on locally

At this point I am stuck...

How do I include bgs.ac.at\Students at this point??

Comment: When you say `Groups` do you mean `OUs`?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there's some confused terminology here between OU and group.  An OU, or Organizational Unit, is basically where you apply group policy.  A group is a bunch of users.

If you want to use the approach in your question, you'll need to create a group that contains the students and refer to that in your policy.

If you want to use Zoredache's approach (recommended), you'll need to create a group that contains the teachers and refer to that in a policy in Computer Configuration -> Preferences -> Control Panel Settings -> Local Users and Groups (replace Domain Users with the Teachers group).

Answer (score 0):

It will be much better to not give login permissions to the users in the first place, instead of trying to deny access.

A simple solution would be to just use a Group policy to modify the membership of the Users group on the local machines.

Remove the `domain.tld\Domain Users` that is added automatically after joining the domain, and then add a security group(s) that contains the set of users you wish to have access to the machine into that group.

So the membership of `.\Users` on Room1 computers might look like this.

- bgs.ac.at\Students
- bgs.ac.at\Teachers

And Room2 might look like this.

- bgs.ac.at\Teachers